# CSS Fixed padings for overflow: scroll

Tags: html, css

With standard behavior of `overflow: scroll` the `padding-bottom` is in the bottom of the scrolled block. But how can I make `padding-bottom` fixed, so odd text will not appear right after bottom border

https://jsfiddle.net/nvg23rp8/6/

```css
body{
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper{
 height: 100px;
 width: 300px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 position: fixed;
 left: 10%;
 top: 10%;
}

.middle{
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
 height: 100%;
 
}

.inner{
 background: blue;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, atque asperiores incidunt aspernatur libero commodi? Quas aspernatur ducimus minima rerum eum veniam, tempora, numquam, fugiat veritatis ea, nemo error totam.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed perspiciatis, nam nulla optio repellendus ratione, at! Ut reiciendis, laboriosam a in soluta odit impedit, quia magnam esse, maxime autem suscipit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: @connexo we have block 100x100px and text more than this block and I need some padding in bottom and top in inner block so text will not appear right after borders when I will scroll it. So how to do this?

Comment: So you want space between the bottom of the "overflow: scroll" and the bottom of the text? Basically, you want the text "hidden" for the bottom X pixels within the box?

Comment: @cale_b yes, something like this

Comment: Is `.inner { margin-bottom: 20px; }` what you are looking for?  I still don't get the question.

Comment: AFAIK, `.inner` is just complicating the question, not really a true factor in this case.

Comment: @connexo no, the text is still on green, and it shouldn't be https://jsfiddle.net/nvg23rp8/7/

Comment: @cale_b ok, so how to do it without `.inner` ?

Comment: You cannot apply the height of the scrollable container's content height in CSS. It's just not available. But if you omit specifying it, you should be done.

Comment: I have simplified your code. Could you tell me if this works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgfj8ayb/

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be helpful.

```css
body{
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper{
 height: 140px;
 width: 300px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 position: fixed;
 left: 10%;
 top: 10%;
}

.middle{
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 height: 100px;
}

.inner{
 background: blue;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 height: 100%;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: .5rem; 
    background: inherit;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #f00;
    border-radius:.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, atque asperiores incidunt aspernatur libero commodi? Quas aspernatur ducimus minima rerum eum veniam, tempora, numquam, fugiat veritatis ea, nemo error totam.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed perspiciatis, nam nulla optio repellendus ratione, at! Ut reiciendis, laboriosam a in soluta odit impedit, quia magnam esse, maxime autem suscipit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I need scrollbar and this code will not work crossbrowserly.

Comment: @AlekseiSievriukov this will work... but not crossbrowserly. :\

Answer (score 0):

CSS is all about illusions!

Make an outer container and give it some padding to give the required illusion. I couldn't get your Fiddle, so I made a new one. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/z9ztcstb/

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.text-container {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  height: 100px;
  /* background: green; */
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In
      quae earum recusandae beatae, optio. Incidunt velit corporis nesciunt, soluta dolor laborum eius recusandae perspiciatis. Est alias minima hic iure, incidunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam alias suscipit, quia, vitae consectetur laudantium nisi itaque odio aliquam dolorem voluptas atque, eos perspiciatis. Excepturi cumque doloribus ad, itaque tempore.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quaerat saepe possimus fuga consequuntur, dolorum facere harum, ullam id similique tempora magni non dolores. Praesentium esse omnis quia eaque quos!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you put the scroll on the inner box, this would be the most effective way of preventing unwanted overflow of text below the blue background. You could do this without the 'inner' css. Try this out. [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/9Lsrrgxt/)

Hope this helps

```js
$('.wrapper').on('scroll', function() {
  $('.inner').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
}

.middle {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  height: 90%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, atque asperiores incidunt aspernatur libero commodi? Quas aspernatur ducimus minima rerum eum veniam, tempora, numquam, fugiat veritatis ea, nemo error totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed perspiciatis, nam nulla optio repellendus ratione, at! Ut reiciendis, laboriosam a in soluta odit impedit, quia magnam esse, maxime autem suscipit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, atque asperiores incidunt aspernatur libero commodi? Quas aspernatur ducimus minima rerum eum veniam, tempora, numquam, fugiat veritatis ea, nemo error totam.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed perspiciatis, nam nulla optio repellendus ratione, at! Ut reiciendis, laboriosam a in soluta odit impedit, quia magnam esse, maxime autem suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi, atque asperiores incidunt aspernatur libero commodi? Quas aspernatur ducimus minima rerum eum veniam, tempora, numquam, fugiat veritatis ea, nemo error totam.
    </div> 
    <div class="border">
     </div> 
 </div>



 div.wrapper {
     width:340px;
     height:120px;
     background-color:#ccc;
     overflow:auto;
     position:relative;
 }
 div.border {
   border:solid 10px red;
   height:100px;
   position:fixed;
   width:300px;
   height:100px;
   top:0;
   left:0;
 }
 div.content{
   z-index:1;
   margin:10px;
 }
```

The main point is to put the border outside of the .wrapper container.
The only issue I can see here is you cannot use mouse wheel to scroll .content inside .wrapper, since it has been overlapped by .border

Here is a JSFiddle link you can see: https://jsfiddle.net/zsydyc/pw9jz5s2/3/